# Thymeleaf - EL1004E: Method call: Method year(java.util.Date) cannot be found on type org.thymeleaf.expression.Calendars

Tags: thymeleaf

I have following configuration to render Thymeleaf template:

```
SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
resolver.setPrefix(pathPrefix);
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
resolver.setOrder(1);
resolver.setCacheable(false);

SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
engine.setDialect(new SpringStandardDialect());
engine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());

engine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
engine.setMessageResolver(new SpringMessageResolver());
engine.setMessageSource(messageSource);

WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request, response, context, pageModel.getLocale());
pageModel.getModel().keySet().forEach(it -> ctx.setVariable(it, pageModel.getModel().get(it)));

return engine.process(viewName, ctx);
```

This renders most of templates without any issue until I use following in template:

```
<span th:text="${#calendars.format(#calendars.createForTimeZone(#calendars.year(listLastModifiedDate), #calendars.month(listLastModifiedDate), #calendars.day(listLastModifiedDate),'UTC'), 'yyyy-MMM-dd')}"></span>
```

I get following error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method year(java.util.Date) cannot be found on type org.thymeleaf.expression.Calendars
```

and template is not rendered.

Seems like a dialect problem, probably I am missing some dialects, but I do not know which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in configuration. I was missing proper Thymeleaf context. Adding this line after `WebContext ctx` initialization solved the issue:

```
ctx.setVariable( 
    ThymeleafEvaluationContext.THYMELEAF_EVALUATION_CONTEXT_CONTEXT_VARIABLE_NAME, 
    new ThymeleafEvaluationContext(applicationContext, new DefaultFormattingConversionService()));
```

Comment: Simply what I was looking for. I was dynamically processing templates and didn't know how to send the correct context. I have no idea how you even found this solution on the first place, but am I glad that you did.

Answer (score 0):

[`#calendars`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.11.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Calendars.html) doesn't have a method `year(java.util.Date)`.  It has a method `year​(Calendar target)`.  The utility object [`#dates`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.11.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Dates.html) however does have a method `year​(Date target)`.

Does this work?

```
<span th:text="${#calendars.format(#calendars.createForTimeZone(#dates.year(listLastModifiedDate), #dates.month(listLastModifiedDate), #dates.day(listLastModifiedDate),'UTC'), 'yyyy-MMM-dd')}" />
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but I actually realized what the problem was. Calendar was fine as it is also valid, but conversion service was not set correctly so valid method was not found due to missing conversion. I had to add DefaultFormattingConversionService to the configuration.